# How I can Add gender and Date of birthday to registration form in Magento Enterprise edition?

Tags: magento

How I  can Add gender and Date of birthday to registration form in Magento Enterprise edition?

I seems Admin->System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration-> Name And Address Options

But I found only two field there. Please refere attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the [backend menu] > Customer > Attributes > Manage Customer Attributes. You're using the standard layouts?

Comment: Yes, I seem there, we need custom code in register.phtml page using the customer attributes code. Right?